# Solve scripts load ordering

Tags: javascript, jquery

Google said my page was rather slow and showed me some 'techniques' to defer load those JS.

Apparently, after I used the technique, it seems that my site other scripts doesn't load because it's slower than External Script fetching. Specifically:

**SCRIPT :**

```
function downloadJSAtOnload() {
    var jq = document.createElement("script");
    jq.src = "path/to/jquery.min.js";
    document.body.appendChild(jq);
    var bs = document.createElement("script");
    bs.src = "path/to/bootstrap.min.js";
    document.body.appendChild(bs);
}
// Check for browser support of event handling capability
if (window.addEventListener)
    window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
    window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;

//Scripts here aren't able to load even though jquery is called above
$('.tips').tooltip();
$(document).ready(function() {/**something here**/
    });
```

---

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: If you're going to asynchronously load your libraries you're going to want to manage your dependencies. I'd recommend using [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) to guarantee correct load order.

Comment: Yes, this is one of those things where unless you're really doing this mostly for the experience, you're way better off using code that's already figured out the various oddities of asynch script loading.

Comment: Hmmm.. I don't think I want to hook in more libraries... I'm looking for a way to this or either sacrifice speed.

Comment: @KoiFish if you know you are going to need the library but want things fast, then just move the script tag to the end of the page right before the body element close

Comment: why don't you try `jQuery.getScript`